# How to overload a comma operator to assign values to an array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comma-operator

So I've got the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class V, unsigned D>
class SparseArray
{
public:

    map<string,V> data;

    SparseArray(){}

    class Index
    {
    private:
        int dims[D]{};
    public:
        int& operator[](int index)
        {
            return dims[index];
        }

        const int& operator[](int index) const
        {
            return dims[index];
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const SparseArray<V,D>::Index& index)
        {
            os << '{';
            for(int i=0;i<D;i++)
            {
                os<<index.dims[i];
                if(i+1!=D)os<<',';
            }
            os << '}';
            return os;
        }
        Index operator,(Index index)
        {

        }

        Index(){for(int i=0;i<D;i++){dims[i]=0;}}
    };

};

int main()
{
SparseArray<int,3>::Index i;

i[0] = 1;
i[1] = 2;
i[2] = 7;

//i = 1,2,7; - that's what i'm trying to make work

cout<<i;
}
```

How do I implement the comma operator so that  `i=1,2,7` will do the exact same thing as doing `i[0] = 1; i[1] = 2; i[2] = 7;`
What i know so far is that `i=1,2,7` is equivalent to `i.operator=(1).operator,(2).operator,(7);` , how do i use this?
I know from research that overloading comma operator is unusual, yet i need to do it as it's in the requirements of the project.

Comment: In your case, it is better to make a copy assignment using initializer list. Then you can write `i = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: The design of your matrix class seems odd. Why not have the `operator[]` (and `operator,`) function in the matrix class itself? What is the purpose of the `Index` class?

Comment: sadly, i have no say in this, and the assignment has to be performed exactly in this style ```i =1,2,7;```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is the beggining of a sparse array project, many of the features are not yet present, for now i'm trying to make ```Index``` class work

Comment: @MateuszC Then let me tell you that you will be violating the meaning of comma operator if you do so. Because only the rightmost operand should be assigned to `i`. Initializer list is the way to move forward.

Comment: @ArdentCoder if the teacher makes me do unholy things, i have no recourse but to listen. At this point in time i cannot negotiate the contents of the task, and have to adapt.

Comment: @MateuszC Fine, I'll help you with that. Did you mean `i.dims` here: "same thing as doing `i[0] = 1; i[1] = 2; i[2] = 7;`"?

Comment: @ArdentCoder yeah, ```i=1,2,7``` should assign values to the underlying ```i.dims``` array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I implement the comma operator so that `obj = 1, 2, 7` will do the
>   exact same thing as doing `obj.arr[0] = 1; obj.arr[1] = 2; obj.arr[2] = 7;`?

This would completely change the meaning of [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). I will prefer initializer list:

```
obj = {1, 2, 7};
```

over the usage of comma operator in this scenario.

> I know from research that overloading comma operator is unusual, yet I
>   need to do it as it's in the requirements of the project.

Yes, I have met such teachers. I think they just want to test whether you can crack their task under these strange constraints. And my solution is based on the hidden clue in your question itself.

> What I know so far is that `obj = 1, 2, 7` is equivalent to
>   `obj.operator=(1).operator,(2).operator,(7);`

Exactly. Notice how `operator,` is almost synonymous to `operator=` in this task:

```
obj.operator=(1).operator=(2).operator=(7);
```

So, it's just a matter of implementing this trick:

```
Sample& Sample::operator,(const int& val)
{
    // simply reuse the assignment operator
    *this = val;

    // associativity of comma operator will take care of the rest
    return *this;
}
```

Implementing `operator=` is upto you.

Then you can do

```
obj = 1, 2, 7;
```

I've made a small working code similar to your example: <kbd>[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Dwj2F9)</kbd>.

**Edit:**

Following Jarod's comment, which proposes a more reasonable overloading of these operators, you can overload `operator=` in this way (*clear + push_back*):

```
Sample& Sample::operator=(const int& val)
{
    arr[0] = val;
    length = 1;
    return *this;
}
```

And `operator,` in this way (*push_back*):

```
Sample& Sample::operator,(const int& val)
{
    // append the value to arr
    arr[length] = val;
    ++length;

    // associativity of comma operator will take care of the rest
    return *this;
}
```

Putting this idea together: <kbd>[Demo 2](https://godbolt.org/z/UQxiyd)</kbd>

Comment: *"Notice how operator, is synonymous to operator= in this task"* OP doesn't have `operator=`, and for me in `obj = 1, 2, 7; obj = 4, 4, 4;` `1, 2, 7` are dropped after second assignment. `obj = 1, 2, 7;` would be more equivalent to `obj = {1, 2, 7};`. so assignment is clear+push_back whereas `,` is just push_back.